# How do I create this layout using CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create the following basic layout:

[image]

And I'm currently using the following basic HTML markup (with slightly different class names and additional markup within each of the HTML elements):

```
<div class="siteContainer">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="topGreenStrip">
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
            <div class="sidebarInnerContainer">
                <div class="brownSection">
                </div>
                <div class="purpleSection">
                </div>
                <div class="pinkSection">
                </div>
                <div class="redSection">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightOrangeStrip">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lightPurpleContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the following *starting* CSS for the markup above:

```
.sidebar {
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.topGreenStrip {
    height: 5px;
    justify-self: flex-start;
}

.sidebarContainer {
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-self: stretch;
}
```

The problem I'm having though is that because I start by stretching everything vertically with flexbox, I don't know how to then stretch things horizontally but still keep everything 100% the height of the screen.

That is, minus the 5px green top strip, I want the rest of the sidebar to occupy 100% the height of the screen. The large pink section should fill in whatever the brown, purple and red sections don't naturally.

I was able to get that part working without the orange bar by using `justify-self: flex-start;`, `justify-self: stretch;` and `justify-self: flex-end;`. However, once I add the orange bar in, I don't know how to keep doing what I'm doing.

The orange bar has a bit of dynamic content in it, so I can't set a static width, and the brown, purple, pink and red sections should use whatever width is not taken up by the orange bar (I'm assuming with `flex-grow: 1;`).

Anyway, how do I get this layout where (within the sidebar), I'm trying to stretch things both to 100% the height and 100% the width? Can I do this with just flexbox, or am I going to have to used positioned/floated elements to get this all to work?

Sorry for the vagueness, but after trying several things and getting nowhere close, I'm not sure where to begin. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `flex-direction: column` on certain elements to stack the children. Also, using `flex: 1` will force that element to grow and fill available space in it's parent.

By setting `height: 100%` on the html and body you can stretch `.siteContainer` to be the full height of the window.

I've added the background colours so you can see the layout in action.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.siteContainer {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}

.topGreenStrip {
  height: 5px;
}

.sidebarContainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebarInnerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.pinkSection,
.lightPurpleContent {
  flex: 1;
}

.topGreenStrip { background: green; }
.brownSection { background: peru; }
.purpleSection { background: darkviolet ; }
.pinkSection { background: pink; }
.redSection { background: red; }
.rightOrangeStrip { background: orange; }
.lightPurpleContent { background: lavender; }
```

```html
<div class="siteContainer">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="topGreenStrip">green
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarContainer">
            <div class="sidebarInnerContainer">
                <div class="brownSection">brown
                </div>
                <div class="purpleSection">purple
                </div>
                <div class="pinkSection">pink
                </div>
                <div class="redSection">red
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightOrangeStrip">orange
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lightPurpleContent">lightpurple
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, itodd. How do I get the `rightOrangeStrip` in there though and get it to also stretch 100% the height while only taking up the minimum amount of horizontal space? Thanks.

Comment: The orange strip is in there, but you can add `.rightOrangeStrip { min-width: 5px }` and adjust as you need